# How should we deal with non-English links?

Tags: discussion

Occasionally, I come across a post ([this is a poor example](https://superuser.com/questions/657596/windows-experience-index-issue), but you catch my drift) that includes a link to a non-English forum, article, or some other type of interweb info-page.

Given our "[linguistics policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)", should we be asking users to pretty please link to the English version (if one is available), and/or otherwise deleting them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with link-only posts, people should be asked to provide an English summary of what they're linking to; the link should only serve as a reference.

If an English version of a linked document is available, users should be asked to link to that version of the document.

If neither is applicable, because no English version exists or the user doesn't respond to the request, flag for deletion or having the post converted to a comment.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to simply edit their post and link to the English version if it's identical? With a courtesy comment, of course.

Comment: @Moses: Sounds great

Comment: Shall we maintain a list of users with different language skillsets? I'll start... *ahem*. I speak English, and Nerd-anese